# Solr Searching - Using Query

Tags: search, solr, solr4, solarium

I have some documents with titles like "Red And Carpet" , "Red and Blue","Blue And Red","Red In White","Blue in Red".

I want to perform search against the title for the following keyword 
"Blue Red".It should return the documents where both Blue and Red Words are available.
According to Above to titles it should return
"Red and Blue",
"Blue And Red",
"Blue in Red".
Documents

ANy Clues on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Search it like this:

> q=title:+blue AND title:+red

Answer (score 1):

You should use an AND query: `title:(Blue AND Red)`

Comment: I need 'if any one search for blue in red' it should return the "blue and red " also. because blue , red is avalable in blue and red. hope you get the point